# fetch обращается к старым данным

Tags: reactjs, fetch

есть приложение при нажатии кнопки передается атрибут urlNews (ссылка на новость)  у каждой новости своя кнопка, отслеживал консолью в функции постоянно меняется URL новости а вот код запомнил старый и держит его пока не нажму в консоле R чтобы обновить. Т.Е. feed постоянно приходит один и тот же пока через консоль принудительно не обновишь. Не понимаю почему

```
function NewsDetail({route, navigation}) {
    const {urlNews, newsDetail, newsTitle} = route.params;
    function getPhoto() {
        //console.log(urlNews)
        let [feed, setFeed] = React.useState('')
        React.useEffect(() => {
            let getFeed = async () => {
                fetch(urlNews)//Запрос исходного кода сайта
                    .then((response) => response.text())
                    .then(result => setFeed(result))
            }
            getFeed();
        }, [])
```

update: urlNews каждый раз разный, т.е.запрос на загрузку страницы каждый раз разный!!! делал так

> fetch(urlNews+ '?random_number=' + new Date().getTime())

Не помогло

Comment: Кешированные данные. Это у вас ведь get запрос. А браузер считает что его можно прокешировать

Comment: можно добавить случайную строку в конец запроса или timestamp

Comment: fetch(urlNews+ '?random_number=' + new Date().getTime()) делал так но не логично!!! у меня urlNews каздый раз разный почему он кешированный запрос делает

Comment: @Gy9vin, не знаю вашу логику программы но `[]` - в `useEffect` обозначает `componentDidMount()`  может быть дело в этом - тут приходится угадывать не видя всего кода, если есть зависимость от роута, то нужно роут добавить в зависимости `[route]`

Comment: @DaniilLoban прав, но если эта функция используеться на нескольких скринах, то лучше использовать [useFocusEffect](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-focus-effect/) что бы убрать лишние рендеры и запросы, на неактивных скринах. Это в теории, гадаем не видя кода. И добавьте, пожалуйста, метку *react-native*, а то будете получать решения, для браузера. А судя по пропсам route и navigation  у вас react-native приложение.